# mkdir+chmod, wrong chmod is set

Tags: chmod, mkdir

I create a directory in php with mkdir().
This is my function:

```
if ( !mkdir( dir_processed_xmls, 0777, true ) ) {
                die('failed: "'.dir_processed_xmls.'" schlug fehl.');
            }
```

I I check the directory on the server, it does not have the chmod rights, I set.

What could be the issue?

Cheers
Lars

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a file or directory, the mask is only the maximum possible mask. Generally the system will subtract world and often group write permissions for security reasons. This means that a generic application can ask for 0o666 (for documents) or 0o777 (for scripts and directories) permissions without worrying about what the local security regime is.